# In cycles my blender render renders twice, the render single layer option does not work

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I try to use the render single layers option to fix this issue like stated in someone else's solution to this problem the frame renders fine however, right at the last moment it switches to the frame rendered before I switched on the option.

I believe I can fix my issues when I remove on of the layers, however I couldn't find any way of doing this.

[image: screen shot of the render layers node]

---

It seems closing my blender as to remove the cashed rendered frame and then re-opening it after witch I tick the render single layer option has solved my problem. Still have no idea how to delete on of the layers tho

Comment: You can delete view layers in the top bar on the right-hand side by selecting the desired view layer and clicking the X button next to it. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The *Render Single Layer* option is to only render the active layer, but it doesn't delete previous renders from the inactive layers. "Active" layer is always the layer which you have selected in the top menu, "inactive" are all the others.

This can be used if you have multiple layers which you combine in the *Compositor* for example with an *Alpha Overlay* node. Let's say one layer is the background, and you have two foreground layers.

First you probably render all of them and you're satisfied with the background but want to tweak the objects in the foreground. Now you go to foreground 1 and rearrange something there, then re-render it to see the result.

You didn't change the background or foreground 2, so you enable *Render Single Layer* while in the foreground 1 layer and render. Only this layer will be rendered, the other two are used from the previous render. Now you could do the same in foreground 2. And if they are both okay, maybe you don't like the background anymore and render that again.

If you don't want a view layer anymore, you can always delete it by clicking the X to the right of its name while you are on this layer. But this also means you lose the settings, in case you might want to use it again later.

So to keep a view layer without deleting it but stop it from being rendered and also not showing up in the *Compositor* from a previous render, you can disable *Use for Rendering* directly above the *Render Single Layer* option. Other than the single layer rendering this doesn't show a previous render of this layer, no matter if it's the active layer when rendering or if you have placed a node for it in the *Compositor*.

With an exception: Enabling *Render Single Layer* overrides a disabled *Use for Rendering* option. This means, even if the view layer should not be used for "normal" rendering, it will be rendered if it's the active layer and *Render Single Layer* is enabled. This can be used if you want to see how this layer looks rendered although you have disabled it for render, without rendering all other layers as well.

By the way, the *Use for Rendering* option can also be animated, let's say you have 500 frames animation with things happening in a background layer and something in a foreground layer. But in only 100 of them is something moving through the foreground etc., then you can render the foreground layer only for this 100 frames and doesn't have to render both foreground and background for all 500 frames.

[image: view layer options]